# Jquery .click() doesn't work in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this strange problem, I never had before and it only occurs in Google Chrome browser.
I have made a function to create a writebutton (that writes a value to my PLC true ajax). 
This is how it looks:

```
    function makeWriteButton(id, address, value, startRefresher){

            $("#" + id).click( function() {
                writeData(address, value, startRefresher);
            });
    }
```

So you pass the id of your input button to that function and the function adds a click event handler, this function works perfect in IE, Firefox, Safari, Opera, but not in Chrome.

Does anyone have any suggestions or reasons why this doesn't work? 
and by the way this function used to work before on chrome but I don't know what I did so it's doesn't work anymore in chrome, really weird.

Comment: Is there anything in the console log in Chrome Developer Tools (F12)?

Comment: Test the output of your id via `alert` or `console.log` and see what you get! For example, inside the click event you can do `alert(id);`

Comment: How do you call `makeWriteButton` function, make sure your `id` is set

Comment: Did you wrap event with `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @djthoms thx for the tip, when I add an alert, the alert is displayed but the value isn't written to my controller (the led doesn't go on) so i know now the problem lies somewhere else, but where because the same code seems to be working fine in IE, FF, etc.

Comment: @GrantThomas can you explain in normal language please?

Comment: @Dom the function declaration is before document.ready but the function is only called inside the document.ready

Comment: What is the OS you are running this on? I have the same problem with Chrome on a iOS5 device

Comment: @Sander_P I'm on a virtual windows 7 machine. I've found out that the click event works because when i add an alert to the event, i get the alert every time, but my ajax request isn't executed so the status of the output on the plc doesn't change

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problem is in that section of code, this worked for me on Chromium

```
<button id="but1">Button1</button>
<button id="but2">Button2</button>
<button id="but3">Button3</button>
<button id="but4">Button4</button>
<button id="but5">Button5</button>

function makeWriteButton(id, address, value, startRefresher) {
    $("#" + id).click(function () {
        alert(address + " " + value + " " + startRefresher);
    });
}

makeWriteButton("but3", 5, 6, 7);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/vKycg/)

Comment: yeah I found out that the code does function properly there must be some problem with my write function, I tested with an alert and i get the alert but the output led on my controller doesn't light up. but I didn't change anything to my write function and it used to work perfectly and it still does but not in chrome :s no problems or what so ever in firefox, safari, opera, ie